# Laravel/Eloquent - Eager Load using other than Primary Key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Eager Loading uses Primary Keys from the parent table inside the IN(...) clause, as clearly stated in Laravel's documentation:

> select * from books
>
> select * from authors where book_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)

Is it possible not to use the Primary Key for this, but another key from the books table? Or even a key retrieved from a pivot table?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah we can do eager loading on non-primary columns. For this you need to define db-data relationships in models:-

Define your models Book & Author like this:-

```
class Books extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'books';    

     public function bookauthors(){
         return $this->has_many('authors','book_id');

     }

}


class Authors extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'authors';


     public function books()
     {
          return  $this->belongs_to('books','book_id');
     }

}
```

Now you can use following line of code to eager load books with authors on a key "book_id":-

```
$books = Books::with(array('bookauthors'))->get();
```

I hope this helps you...i haven't tested on my local or test db. But had used similar eager loading for posts-tags relationship.